# Tabs using ACF repeater plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Repeater plugin for display content using tabs, But tabs not working fine here is my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs course-detail-tabs">
<?php                            
if( have_rows('test-course') ): $i = 0;
while ( have_rows('test-course') ) : the_row(); $i++;
?>                               
<li class="<?php if($i == 1){echo "active";}?>"><a href="tab<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php the_sub_field('tname'); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;                           
?>  
</ul>
<div class="tab-content course-tab-content">
<?php                            
if( have_rows('test-course') ): $i = 0;
while ( have_rows('test-course') ) : the_row(); $i++;
?>                               
<div class="tab-pane fade <?php if($i == 1){echo "active in";}?>" id="tab<?php echo $i; ?>">
<section class="course-schedule">
<?php the_sub_field('timg'); ?>
</section>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;                           
?>                                 
</div>
```

Anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: records are being displayed .. only tabbing not working right ?

Comment: Yes, I think problem with this <div class="tab-pane fade <?php if($i == 1){echo "active in";}?>" id="tab<?php echo $i; ?>"> not assigning class "active in" for current tab.

Comment: what is the value of id="tab<?php echo $i; ?>" you can check by inspect element.. whether its 1 for 1st div.. 

Also try changing the variable since $i has been used above also.. might can solve the issue

Comment: Ya checked using inspect element, problem is "active in" not changing when I click on second tab, It still on first tab.

Comment: But It's working fine for static HTML tabs

Comment: what is the js you are using for tabbing .. ? just provide me the name .

Comment: I think it's bootstrap tabs bcz class names like this "nav nav-tabs"